# MVC edit data via modal dialog according to dropdownlist selected value

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, dropdownlistfor

I have a table in an MVC solution filled with data such as person details (name surname etc). Upon clicking edit I would like either a modal dialog where user could edit the data or a new page (as it is currently coded) where user can edit the data. 
However, one of the data is a dropdownlist and when the user selects a particular value from this dropdownlist I would like to display a modal dialog for the user to enter one or two more fields related to the dropdownlist value selected.

Are there any examples I could follow either via javascript or ajax to achieve the above? Thanks

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20851165/bootstrap-modal-form-does-not-close-after-submit

Comment: Try using jqgrid form editing- http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing